# Django MySQL on a different database

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

So for example, here are the databases that are set in my **settings.py** file.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'app_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'postgres_user',
        'PASSWORD': 's3krit'
    },
    'my_blog': {
        'NAME': 'my_blog',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': '192.168.1.40',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'priv4te'
    }
}
```

I need to get some information from **my_blog** database.
I do not have write permissions to this database, I only need to perform simple `select` queries.
How do you suggest I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you multiple database, what you need to do is to change database routing rules for the queries that you are making for the same.

You can read up more here. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/

```
class MyBlogRouter(object):
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    auth application.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read blog models go to my_blog.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'my_blog':
            return 'my_blog'
        return None
```

And in your settings.py

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.MyBlogRouter',]
```

Comment: and how should I write my model, for example?

Comment: Model and it's fields should contain schema structure picked up from database structure. Once you are done with that. You need to create a fake migration for it. So that proper content types is generated for your Django App. Then the above should do it. Test it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please do below in your Data fetching implementation.

```
from django.db import connections

cursor = connections['my_blog'].cursor()
cursor.execute('yourquery')
data = cursor.fetchall() # fetches all rows
data = cursor.fetchone() # fetches one row
```

Comment: Thank you, this works too. Still trying to find the best way though.

Comment: This will be helpful when it comes to the point where I should use complicated join queries, I guess.

Comment: When you said, you don't have write access to database means you are not going to create tables using django models on that database. Also, i would not suggest writing a database router given that you will only be using it for SELECT queries. What you can do is to write a Global method in your Django project which will make connection to my_blog database and return the query data. do you have the django models for the corresponding database table ? if yes, then you can write a router.

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyword "using" for this purpose .

```
SomeModel.objects.using('my_blog').all()
```

Apart from this you can route request(READ/WRITE/UPDATE) , using making your custom db routers.

For more information read : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/